# Not able to lift sails in production mode.(sails lift --prod --verbose not working)

Tags: javascript, node.js, sails.js

I wanted to lift my sails aap in production mode.when i run sails lift --prod --verbose, i am getting bunch of errors.
My local.js file looks like this.

```
  /**
     * Local environment settings
*
 * While you're developing your app, this config file should include
 * any settings specifically for your development computer (db   passwords, etc.)
 * When you're ready to deploy your app in production, you can use   this file
 * for configuration options on the server where it will be deployed.
 *
 *
 * PLEASE NOTE:
 *        This file is included in your .gitignore, so if you're using  git
 *        as a version control solution for your Sails app, keep in   mind that
 *        this file won't be committed to your repository!
 *
 *        Good news is, that means you can specify configuration for your local
 *        machine in this file without inadvertently committing personal information
 *        (like database passwords) to the repo.  Plus, this prevents other members
 *        of your team from commiting their local configuration changes on top of yours.
 *
 *
 * For more information, check out:
 * http://sailsjs.org/#documentation
 */
var config={

development:{
    connections: {

            mongo: {
            adapter: 'sails-mongo',
            host: 'localhost',
            user: '',
            password: '',
            database: 'mydata',
            schema: true
        }
    },
    mailer:{
        hostUrl:'http://localhost:1337/',
        emailConfirm:'confirm/',
        inviteMoreFriends:'myspace'
    },
    geoSpatial:{
        radiusOfEarth:6375,
        radius:3,
        maxRecords:20
    },
    facebook:{
        clientID: "CLIENT ID",
        clientSecret: "SECRET",
        callbackURL: "http://www.EXAMPLE.com:1337/auth/facebook/callback"
    }
}
}
module.exports = {


// The `port` setting determines which TCP port your app will be deployed on
// Ports are a transport-layer concept designed to allow many different
// networking applications run at the same time on a single computer.
// More about ports: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Port_(computer_networking)
//
// By default, if it's set, Sails uses the `PORT` environment variable.
// Otherwise it falls back to port 1337.
//
// In production, you'll probably want to change this setting
// to 80 (http://) or 443 (https://) if you have an SSL certificate

port: process.env.PORT || 1337,


// The runtime "environment" of your Sails app is either 'development' or 'production'.
//
// In development, your Sails app will go out of its way to help you
// (for instance you will receive more descriptive error and debugging output)
//
// In production, Sails configures itself (and its dependencies) to optimize performance.
// You should always put your app in production mode before you deploy it to a server-
// This helps ensure that your Sails app remains stable, performant, and scalable.
//
// By default, Sails sets its environment using the `NODE_ENV` environment variable.
// If NODE_ENV is not set, Sails will run in the 'development' environment.

environment: process.env.NODE_ENV || 'development',


development: {
    //config is placed as the attributes needed by aws config node module
    aws: {
        region: 'REGION',
        accessKeyId: 'KEY ID',
        secretAccessKey: 'SECRET',
        cloudFrontCDN: 'EXAMPLE.cloudfront.net'
    },
    s3: {
        Bucket: 'MY_BUCKET',
        endpoint: 'ENDPOINT',
        imageUrl: 'URL'
    },
    uploads: {
        thumbnails: __dirname + '/../uploads/thumbnails/'
    }



},
likeprod: {
    //config is placed as the attributes needed by aws config node module
    aws: {
        region: 'REGION',
        accessKeyId: 'KEY ID',
        secretAccessKey: 'SECRET',
        cloudFrontCDN: 'EXAMPLE.cloudfront.net'
    },
    s3: {
        Bucket: 'MY_BUCKET',
        endpoint: 'ENDPOINT',
        imageUrl: 'URL'
    },
    uploads: {
        thumbnails: __dirname + '/../uploads/thumbnails/'
    }


},

mandrillApiKey:"API_KEY",
twilio:{
    accountSid:'SECRET',
    authToken:'TOKEN'
},
metaPublic:{
    groupBookNumber:'+0123456789'
},

    connections:config[process.env.NODE_ENV].connections,
    mailer:config[process.env.NODE_ENV].mailer,
    geoSpatial:config[process.env.NODE_ENV].geoSpatial,
    facebook:config[process.env.NODE_ENV].facebook,

//TODO: refactor the config[environment] as for connections
current: function () {
    return sails.config[sails.config.environment]
}
```

};

when i run sails lift --prod. I am getting this error.

```
 $ sails lift --prod --verbose

info: Starting app...

verbose: Please run `npm install coffee-script` to use coffescript     (skipping for now)
verbose: Setting Node environment...
verbose: moduleloader hook loaded successfully.
verbose: Loading app config...

/home/vgulp/Desktop/config/local.js:136
connections:config[process.env.NODE_ENV].connections,
                                        ^
TypeError: Cannot read property 'connections' of undefined
at Object.<anonymous> (/home/Desktop/vka/config/local.js:136:45)
at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
at require (module.js:380:17)
at       /home/Desktop/vka/node_modules/sails/node_modules/include-all/index.js:129:29
at Array.forEach (native)
at requireAll (/home/Desktop/vka/node_modules/sails/node_modules/include-all/index.js:44:9)
at buildDictionary (/home/Desktop/vka/node_modules/sails/node_modules/sails-build-dictionary/index.js:68:14)
at Function.module.exports.aggregate (/home/Desktop/vka/node_modules/sails/node_modules/sails-build-dictionary/index.js:190:9)
at Array.loadOtherConfigFiles [as 0] (/home/Desktop/vka/node_modules/sails/lib/hooks/moduleloader/index.js:102:22)
at /home/Desktop/vka/node_modules/sails/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:459:38
at Array.forEach (native)
at _each (/home/Desktop/vka/node_modules/sails/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:32:24)
at Object.async.auto (/home/Desktop/vka/node_modules/sails/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:430:9)
```

Can anyone suggest a solution.

Comment: Is this app deployed to an instance on Amazon EC2? Have you checked your [security groups](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/using-network-security.html) to make sure that port 1337 is open to traffic?

Comment: Yes, it is deployed on Amazon EC2 and port 1337 is open to traffic.

Comment: I downvoted you for completely changing your question after an answer was already provided.
If you have a new / different question, ask a new question and add a comment linking to the new one so people can follow if needed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don 't have connection specified for `production` in `local.js` (As you are running from your Desktop)

As the error rightly says,

> connections:config[process.env.NODE_ENV].connections,
>                                           ^
>   TypeError: Cannot read property 'connections' of undefined

`process.env.NODE_ENV` is `production` when running in `--prod`

```
var config = {

    development: {
        connections: {

            mongo: {
                adapter: 'sails-mongo',
                host: 'localhost',
                user: '',
                password: '',
                database: 'mydata',
                schema: true
            }
        },
        mailer: {
            hostUrl: 'http://localhost:1337/',
            emailConfirm: 'confirm/',
            inviteMoreFriends: 'myspace'
        },
        geoSpatial: {
            radiusOfEarth: 6375,
            radius: 3,
            maxRecords: 20
        },
        facebook: {
            clientID: "CLIENT ID",
            clientSecret: "SECRET",
            callbackURL: "http://www.EXAMPLE.com:1337/auth/facebook/callback"
        }
    },
    production: {
        connections: {

            mongo: {
                adapter: 'sails-mongo',
                host: 'localhost',
                user: '',
                password: '',
                database: 'mydata',
                schema: true
            }
        },
        mailer: {
            hostUrl: 'http://localhost:1337/',
            emailConfirm: 'confirm/',
            inviteMoreFriends: 'myspace'
        },
        geoSpatial: {
            radiusOfEarth: 6375,
            radius: 3,
            maxRecords: 20
        },
        facebook: {
            clientID: "CLIENT ID",
            clientSecret: "SECRET",
            callbackURL: "http://www.EXAMPLE.com:1337/auth/facebook/callback"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It worked, but i m getting a new error in bootstrap.js.

Comment: /bootstrap.js:165
        mkdirp(sails.config.current().uploads.thumbnails,function(err){
                                     ^
TypeError: Cannot read property 'uploads' of undefined
    at createUploadDirectories (/home/vgulp/Desktop/funvgulp/config/bootstrap.js:165:38)

Comment: @VaibhavKumarAmbeshta update the question with contents of `bootstrap.js` or start a new question.

Comment: @VaibhavKumarAmbeshta change `likeprod` in `local.js` to `production`

Comment: yes i have changed it. Sails lift --prod is working fine.

Comment: But i ma getting error when running localhost:1337.

Comment: A server error was encountered in a request...
But no response could be sent because an error occurred:
 [TypeError: Cannot read property 'util' of undefined]

Comment: Unable to parse HTTP body- error occurred:
Error: Redis connection to 10.130.212.246:6379 failed - connect ETIMEDOUT
    at RedisClient.flush_and_error (/home/ubuntu/funvgulp/node_modules/sails/node_modules/connect-redis/node_modules/redis/index.js:142:13)

Comment: at RedisClient.on_error (/home/ubuntu/funvgulp/node_modules/sails/node_modules/connect-redis/node_modules/redis/index.js:180:10)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (/home/ubuntu/funvgulp/node_modules/sails/node_modules/connect-redis/node_modules/redis/index.js:95:14)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/96873/discussion-between-mjzac-and-vaibhav-kumar-ambeshta).

Comment: @VaibhavKumarAmbeshta can you accept the answer if it helped?

Answer (score 3):

[ Edited: the following answer was based on the original question which was completely changed by the author ]

Your sails app need to lift in production mode or you need to specify the port to be used in your config files.

Production mode runs your express server on port 80.

Is your AWS instance setup to lift the app in production mode?

http://sailsjs.org/documentation/anatomy/my-app/config/env/production-js

Comment: Yes, I can lift the sails app in production mode, I can access it by typing xx.xx.xxx.xx:1337. How can i access the app with the AWS public Ip without specifying the port.

Comment: You have to lift on port 80 (default non-ssl web client port). This is the default port use when lifting in production.